# Have to restart Visual Studio Code to elimante mistakenly shown errors

Tags: visual-studio-code

sometimes my changes cause an error and after fixing it, VS Code wont get rid of the error. In that case I have to close VS Code and reopen it.

Example:

I add at first an click-event to an html-element, that isnt defined yet in the component.ts File. Angular shows the red unterline and the error message. After defining the missing function, the error does not disapper (even if I save all files and/or refresh explorer). I have to restart VS Code.

Of course I can prevent this using the right order. But sometimes there are errors like this.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Can you tell us the version of VS code?

Comment: Version 1.33.1 :)